# txt file with different seperators to lists of integers

Tags: python-3.x, list, txt

I have a txt file with integers, some seperated by spaces and some seperated by comma's.

it looks like this:

```
7,4,9,5,11,17,23,2,0,14,21,24,10,16,13,6,15,25,12,22,18,20,8,19,3,26,1

22 13 17 11  0

8  2 23  4 24

21  9 14 16  7

6 10  3 18  5
```

I want to create 2 lists, 1 list with the first csv's and 1 list of sublists with the other lines of integers like this:

```
list_1 = [7,4,9,5,11,17,23,2,0,14,21,24,10,16,13,6,15,25,12,22,18,20,8,19,3,26,1]
list_2 = [[22, 13, 17, 11,  0], [8,  2, 23,  4, 24], [21,  9, 14, 16,  7], [6, 10,  3, 18,  5]]
```

I cant quite get the result im looking for, anyone that can help me out?

I've tried different ways of loading them in but I always get errors because of the different seperators:

```
 b=[[int(x) for x in i.split()] for i in open("file", "r").readlines()]
```

can't read the comma separated values for instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
list_1 = []
list_2 = []

with open("your_file.txt", "r") as f_in:
    for line in map(str.strip, f_in):
        if line == "":
            continue
        if "," in line:
            list_1.extend(map(int, line.split(",")))
        else:
            list_2.append(list(map(int, line.split())))

print(f"{list_1=}")
print(f"{list_2=}")
```

Prints:

```py
list_1=[7, 4, 9, 5, 11, 17, 23, 2, 0, 14, 21, 24, 10, 16, 13, 6, 15, 25, 12, 22, 18, 20, 8, 19, 3, 26, 1]
list_2=[[22, 13, 17, 11, 0], [8, 2, 23, 4, 24], [21, 9, 14, 16, 7], [6, 10, 3, 18, 5]]
```

Comment: I get a TypeError: 'list' object is not callable. Any idea why this is?

Comment: @Willem12345 You probably assigned to the `list` variable before. Don't do that, use other name than `list`